# Performing calculations based on customer ID in comma-separated file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that contains several comma-separated columns, including a customer ID in the first column. 
One customer ID may occur on several rows, but always refers to the same real customer.

How do I run basic calculations in a shell script based on this ID column?  For example, calculating the sum of the mileages (the 5th field) for the given customer ID.

```
102,305,Jin,Kerala,40         
104,308,Paul,US,45             
105,350,Nina,AUS,50           
102,390,Jin,Kerala,10           
104,395,Paul,US,35               
102,399,Jin,Kerala,35
```

5th field is the mileage, 1st field is the customer ID.

Comment: I would just import that into some database, like SQLite and do all the math as SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple `awk` script that will sum up the mileages and print the customer IDs together with the sums at the end:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "," }

{
    customer_id = $1;
    mileage = $5;
    total_mileage[customer_id] += mileage;
}

END {
    for (customer_id in total_mileage) {
        print customer_id, total_mileage[customer_id];
    }
}
```

To run (after making it executable with `chmod +x script.awk`):

```
$ ./script.awk data.in
102 85
104 80
105 50
```

Alternatively, as a "one-liner":

```
$ awk -F, '{t[$1]+=$5} END {for (c in t){print c,t[c]}}' data.in
102 85
104 80
105 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of unique IDs using something like (assuming the first column is the ID):

```
awk '{print $1}' inputFile | sort -u
```

This outputs the first field of every single line in the input file `inputFile`, sorts them and removes duplicates.

You can then use that method with a `bash` loop to process each of the unique IDs with another `awk` command to perform some action on them. In the following snippet, I print out the matching lines for each ID:

```
for id in $(awk '{print $1}' inputFile | sort -u) ; do
    echo "${id}:"
    awk -vid=${id} '$1==id {print "  "$0)' inputFile
done
```

In that code, for each individual ID, it first outputs the ID then uses `awk` to only process lines matching that ID. The action carried out is to output the full line with indentation.

Of course, you can do anything you wish with the lines matching each ID. As shown below, an example more closely matching your requirements.

First, here's an input file I used for testing - we can assume field 1 is the customer ID and field 2 the mileage:

```
$ cat inputFile
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
b 8
c 9
b 10
c 11
c 12
```

And here's a command-line transcript of the method proposed (note that `$` and `+` are input prompt and continuation prompt respectively, they are not part of the actual commands):

```
$ for id in $(awk '{print $1}' inputFile | sort -u) ; do
+    awk -vid=${id} '
+        $1==id {print $0; sum += $2 }
+        END    {print "Total: "sum; print }
+        ' inputFile
+ done

a 1
a 4
a 7
Total: 12

b 2
b 5
b 8
b 10
Total: 25

c 3
c 6
c 9
c 11
c 12
Total: 41
```

---

Keep in mind that, for non-huge data sets, it's also possible to do this in a single pass `awk` script, using associative arrays to store the totals then outputting all the data in the `END` block. I myself tend to prefer the multi-pass approach myself since it minimises the possibility of running out of memory. The trade-off, of course, is that it will no doubt take longer since you're processing the file more than once.

For a single-pass solution, you can use something like:

```
$ awk '{sum[$1] += $2} {for (key in sum) { print key": "sum[key]}}' inputFile
```

which gives you:

```
a: 12
b: 25
c: 41
```

Comment: Downvote: doing it all in a single Awk script would be the standard solution; aggregate into an array by id, then in the END block, loop over the id keys and print. Also there is a pnesky typo in the first code fragment.

Comment: @tripleee, fixed the typo. However, I've been bitten too many times in the past by trying to load huge datasets into `awk` so I prefer the multi-pass approach - I'll try to explain it better in the body. As to the downvote, that's your right, but I believe you may have a slightly distorted definition of "not useful" (but no offence taken). The fact that there are other approaches does not, in my *opinion*, make this approach a bad one. But, in any case, I agree that this is a duplicate so should probably be closed.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @wilx that using a database might be smarter, this sample `awk` script should get you started:

```
awk -v FS=',' '{miles[$1] += $5}
  END { for (customerid in miles) {
      print customerid, miles[customerid]; } }' customers
```